# Path Environment Variable Windows 10. Echo %Path% on command prompt shows only %Path%

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path, echo

My variable value in path is as follows

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;%PYTHON_HOME%\;%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts;C:\SQLite
```

When I type `echo %Path%` on command prompt, I get below output

```
PS C:\Users\Arun> echo %Path%
%Path%
```

Why is this?

Comment: if you see `PS` at the start of the prompt `PS C:\Users\Arun>` then it's the default prompt string of powershell, not cmd

Comment: google second system

Answer (score 84):

PowerShell uses a different syntax than Windows Command Prompt.

Use `$Env:Path` or `Get-ChildItem Env:Path` to retrieve the PATH variable.

Source: [Creating and Modifying Environment Variables - Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx)

Answer (score 27):

Since Windows 10 Insider Build 14971 Microsoft changed the default command shell to be `PowerShell` instead of `cmd`.

PowerShell handles environment variables differently to `cmd`.

To display their values in PowerShell use the following syntax:

```
$Env:variablename
```

Example:

```
> echo %Path%
%Path%
> $Env:Path
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apps\WSCC\Sysinternals Suite;C:\apps\WSCC\NirSoft Utilities
>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of Windows PowerShell commands](http://ss64.com/ps/) - An excellent reference for all things PowerShell related.
- [Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-env.html)
- [Take Charge of Environment Variables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell)